# MATLAB - padarray()

Tags: matlab

I have the FFT of an image that is a 55x36 complex double, I'm trying to make it 760x1064 by zero-padding. I'm using the padarray() function but for some reason it's not padding by the amount I want.

IMAGE1 in the following is 55x36

```
padarray(IMAGE1, [760-55 1064-36])
```

This gives me a 1465x2902 not a 760x1064. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padarray`, by default, pads both before and after your array. So your resulting matrix will have a size of `705+55+705 = 1465` in the first dimension. If you want to pad only after your array in each dimension, you can use the `'post'` option, if you wanted to pad before your array you can use the `'pre'` option.

```
A = padarray(IMAGE1, [760-55 1064-36], 'post');
size(A)

ans =

         760        1064
```